# How to log in the controller the 499 generated by client timeout Micronaut

Tags: java, http, kotlin, controller, micronaut

Hi i want to know how much time the request is trying to process before the client reaches the timeout. im using Micronaut with simple @Controller annotation

```
@Controller
open class SomeController {

    @Get("/url")
    @Trace
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ContinueSpan
    open fun getUrl(
        
    ): Single<MutableHttpResponse<Any>> {

        return service.process()
            .flatMap {
                Single.fromCallable {
                    Thread.sleep(5000) //simulate delay
                    it
                }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            }
            .map { HttpResponse.ok(it) }
            .doOnError {
                println("some error ${it.message}")
               
            }.doOnSuccess {
                println("all ok ${it.status().code}")
            }.doOnDispose {
                println("dispose running")
            }.doOnSubscribe {
                println("init")
            }
    }
}
```

And im getting only the init log and the all ok log with status code of 200, I want to get the 499 or the timeout logged and also the time spent in the request (start to timeout) using Micronaut